# Not able to run my node app at port 80 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm, npm-start

I want to run my node app at port 80 in ubuntu 16.04. But the moment I'm trying to run my app with `npm start` its throwing error **Port in already in use** whereas it's not in use. According to [Github Reply](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7327), We need root privileges to run on ports below 1048 which is correct.
So the moment I'm trying to run my app like this `sudo npm install` it's throwing **sudo: npm: command not found**

So can anyone suggest me, how to run `npm start` with **root privileges** on ubuntu. I did googling but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sudo and npm(including node) should be same directory. For example sudo is always available in `/usr/bin/` so after installing npm and node should also go in `/usr/bin/`. earlier I was using NVM to install node and npm. I removed `.nvm` directory and referred [node installation link](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-the-latest-node-js-and-nmp-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-lts/) which placed both npm and node in `/usr/bin/`. And then now I'm able to run npm with sudo.

Answer (score 1):

First run `which npm` to get the full path to npm.

Then run `sudo FULL_PATH_TO_NPM start`.

Or to make a one-liner:

```
sudo $(which npm) start
```

Comment: I tried this "sudo /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/bin/npm start" but it thrown the error like "/usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory" whereas I have kept "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/" environment variables path. I can see version for both using node -v --> v8.11.4 and npm -v --> 6.4.1

Comment: OK so your problem is your `node` and `npm` are not in root's `$PATH`.  No surprise, see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path - you need to set `$PATH` inside the root environment, there are various solutions there.

Comment: Somehow this leads me to the solution, writing answer below. Thank you very much @John.